# How get.time() function created in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

why only time consideration is taken 1970 year as base for the getTime() function?

i am working on time and date functions and i struck at where this date and time was invented and as according to what base our time zone was set?

Comment: Because 00:00:00 UTC 1 January 1970 is the beginning of [the UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: Hi, take a glance at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). About your question, it's not javascript related. Computer science needed a way to track dates, and unix timestamp was just one of them. 1970 is a conventional date, it has no particular meaning